# How to get index name from sys.dm_tran_locks

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-management-views

I'm working on a multi-tenanted solution. As such we have a lot of databases on our SQL Server. I'm looking at a locking issue and need to be able to see which locks are being waited on.

I have queried the [sys.dm_tran_locks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190345.aspx) dynamic view, but would like to also include the, database, object and index names referred to by the resource_associated_entity_id column. This links through to the [sys.partitions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175012(v=sql.110).aspx) table, but that table only returns rows for the current database and the locks I'm looking at are distributed around several databases.

Is there a way to get this information without creating a cursor and using dynamically generated queries?

Comment: Martin : I just noticed that I forgot to put in the usage regarding passing in the DatabaseName. I realize you have already marked it as accepted, but updated anyway to be clear about what I was meaning in terms of making it real easy-like :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically "no". There is no meta-data function that will get index names outside of the current database context. This sad fact also adversely affects using the following when trying to use them in a similarly useful manner:

- [sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188917.aspx)
- [sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188917.aspx)
- [sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188755.aspx)

So you have two options:

- Dynamic SQL (as you have suspected)
- A SQLCLR function that accepts all required IDs, including `database_id`, and connects via "context connection = true" to query the intended system view (which is how I have solved this issue in terms of index names and sys.objects in [SQL#](http://www.SQLsharp.com/), but the technique of taking in `database_id` as a parameter to a SQLCLR Function--Scalar or TVF--and having it connect locally via dynamically built SQL to said database would work the same for any other meta-data).
  **EDIT**
  To make it even easier, pass in the database name and concatenate that into the `SqlCommand.CommandText` and use the IDs as `SqlParameter`s. So the signature would be, in terms of getting the index name:
  `GetIndexName(@DatabaseName sysname, @object_id INT, @index_id INT)`
  and used as follows:
  `GetIndexName(DB_NAME(dmv.database_id), dmv.object_id, dmv.index_id)`

Just FYI, here is a list of meta-data functions, grouped by whether or not you can specify the database or are current-database-only:

**Can Specify Database**

- [INDEX_COL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178545.aspx) (via fully-qualified object name)
- [OBJECT_ID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190328.aspx) (via fully-qualified object name)
- [OBJECT_NAME](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186301.aspx) (via `database_id` parameter)
- [OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb326599.aspx) (via `database_id` parameter)

**Current-Database-Only**

- [INDEXPROPERTY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187729.aspx)
- [OBJECT_DEFINITION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176090.aspx)
- [OBJECTPROPERTY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176105.aspx)
- [OBJECTPROPERTYEX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188390.aspx)
- [SCHEMA_ID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188797.aspx)
- [SCHEMA_NAME](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175068.aspx)
- [TYPE_ID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181628.aspx)
- [TYPE_NAME](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189750.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: no, there's no way to avoid this. `sys.partitions` and other database-specific views are annoying that way. For entire objects, you can usually get around this with `OBJECT_NAME()`, since that takes a database ID. For allocation IDs, you're out of luck.

Technically speaking, you can avoid writing cursors yourself by using our old pal `sp_msforeachdb`, but since that's not documented and usually doesn't give the results in the format you want anyway, writing it yourself is a better idea.

Because `sys.dm_tran_locks` is highly dynamic, it won't be easy to get the locking information at just the time you need it. A possible alternative is to use a profiler trace or extended event session to get the exact sequence of locks acquired (obviously, since this is tons of data, you would only do this when troubleshooting specific queries). If all you need is to know who's holding up things at the time the proverbial shit hits the fan, `sp_msforeachdb 'dbcc opentran(''?'')'` is still surprisingly effective.